# How to scale objects to a certain size?

Tags: actionscript-3, scale, scaling

I have a question about scaling objects. I have a function that calculates the target scale of a group of objects. The scale is dependant on the amount of objects. At the same time I want the objects to have a maximum scale. I want the objects to be no bigger than 55 pixels wide. So I divide the 55 by the object width to get the maximum scale. So I came up with the following function:

```
private function setScale():Number
{
//The 6 is just a random number I chose.
    scale = 6/amountObjects;
    if (scale >= 55/averageObjectWidth)
    {
        scale = 55/averageObjectWidth;
    }
    return scale;
}
```

The problem I have is that when I perform this function multiple times I eventually get the wrong scale. I'll illustrate this in the following example:

I have ten objects, so the scale would be 0.6. 
The average object width is 138, so the maximum scale is about 0.4. 
So I would then scale the objects with this scale factor. The new width would be then 55.
Then when the amount of objects changes I run this function again. Now there are 9 objects, the new scale based on the amount of objects becomes about 0.7. Here is the pickle now, since the new object width is 55 when I do `scale = 55/averageObjectWidth`... I get 1! Meaning that it will skip the if statement and return me a scale of 0.7.

All I want to do is have this class return me a scale based on the amount of objects, that is still under the width of 55.

I hope I was clear enough and thank you for your time.

Comment: 55 pixels per object, or for all of the objects combined?

Comment: Oh sorry it's 55 px per object.

Answer (score 0):

Would I be right in assuming that these objects are Sprites?
In which case when you set the scale/width/height of the sprite you are setting its scale. So to get the 'true'/unscaled width you could use sprite.width / sprite.scaleX (or set the scale back to 1, but you'd have to set it back again, that may cause weird graphical glitches)